# Iterate a format string over a list

Tags: python, formatting, iteration, language-comparisons

In Lisp, you can have something like this:

```
(setf my-stuff '(1 2 "Foo" 34 42 "Ni" 12 14 "Blue"))
(format t "~{~d ~r ~s~%~}" my-stuff)
```

What would be the most Pythonic way to iterate over that same list? The first thing that comes to mind is:

```
mystuff = [1, 2, "Foo", 34, 42, "Ni", 12, 14, "Blue"]
for x in xrange(0, len(mystuff)-1, 3):
    print "%d %d %s" % tuple(mystuff[x:x+3])
```

But that just feels awkward to me. I'm sure there's a better way?

---

Well, unless someone later provides a better example, I think gnibbler's solution is the nicest\closest, though it may not be quite as apparent at first how it does what it does:

```
mystuff = [1, 2, "Foo", 34, 42, "Ni", 12, 14, "Blue"]
for x in zip(*[iter(mystuff)]*3):
    print "{0} {1} {2}".format(*x)
```

Comment: As an aside, isn't awkward such a terribly wonderful word? It just *looks* awkward!

Comment: It looks awkward in comparison but it really isn't that bad.

Comment: +1 because I have no clue if you were referring to my comment or the code. *Please* don't clarify, the ambiguity is much more entertaining/interesting!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
mystuff = [1, 2, "Foo", 34, 42, "Ni", 12, 14, "Blue"]
for x in zip(*[iter(mystuff)]*3):
    print "%d %d %s"%x
```

Or using `.format`

```
mystuff = [1, 2, "Foo", 34, 42, "Ni", 12, 14, "Blue"]
for x in zip(*[iter(mystuff)]*3):
    print "{0} {1} {2}".format(*x)
```

If the format string is not hardcoded, you can parse it to work out how many terms per line

```
from string import Formatter
num_terms = sum(1 for x in Formatter().parse("{0} {1} {2}"))
```

Putting it all together gives

```
mystuff = [1, 2, "Foo", 34, 42, "Ni", 12, 14, "Blue"]
fmt = "{0} {1} {2}"
num_terms = sum(1 for x in Formatter().parse(fmt))
for x in zip(*[iter(mystuff)]*num_terms):
    print fmt.format(*x)
```

Comment: I *really* like this solution, and I was really confused at first but after hacking at the code that is really elegant.

Answer (score 6):

I think `join` is the most similar feature in Python:

```
(format t "~{~D, ~}" foo)

print(foo.join(", "))
```

It's a little worse when you have multiple items inside, as you see, though if you have a [group-by](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/303060-group-a-list-into-sequential-n-tuples/) function (which is really useful anyway!), I think you can make it work without too much trouble.  Something like:

```
mystuff = [1, 2, "Foo", 34, 42, "Ni", 12, 14, "Blue"]
print(["%d %d %s" % x for x in group(mystuff, 3)].join("\n"))
```

Comment: Yes, with the addition of a specialized generator function you could make it look really nice.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it depends on how much you want to cheat.  You could port `FORMAT` to Python and say `FORMAT(True, "~{~d ~r ~s~%~}", my_stuff)`, if you were really bored some weekend.  :-)

Comment: I've been tempted! Of course I also wish that the `~r` were part of Python libs, too... There's already a module on sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pynum2word/

Answer (score 4):

For starters, I'd use the newer string formatting methods in 2.6+

```
print "{0} {1} {2}".format(*mystuff[x:x+3])
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd say the most Pythonic would be to make the list deeper:

```
mystuff = [(1, 2, "Foo"), (34, 42, "Ni"), (12, 14, "Blue")]
for triplet in mystuff:
    print "%d %d %s" % triplet
```

Comment: that's basically what gnibblers solution creates: `[x for x in zip(*[iter(mystuff)]*3)]` = `[(1, 2, 'foo'), (34, 42, 'ni'), (12, 14, 'blue')]` Pretty slick, neh?

Comment: I know that, but I think it's more Pythonic just to have the list in that form to begin with.  That was the original question, right?

Comment: Well, I was a little ambiguous, so I fixed the wording. I really was more interested in the iterating/formatting part - consuming a certain # of list values per iteration. But in terms of the whole "program", your solution would be more pythonic

Answer (score 2):

```
stuff = [1, 2, "Foo", 34, 42, "Ni", 12, 14, "Blue"]

it = iter(stuff)
itn = it.next

print '\n'.join("%d %d %s" % (el,itn(),itn())
                for el in it)
```

Very understandable, I think

Answer (score 0):

A two liner based on Wright:

```
mystuff = [1, 2, "Foo", 34, 42, "Ni", 12, 14, "Blue"]
print '\n'.join("{0},{1},{2}".format(*mystuff[x:x+3]) for x in xrange(0, len(mystuff)-1, 3))
```