# Not able to generate HTML code correctly

Tags: python, html

I am trying to read a list,values can be single or it can have multiple entries seperated by a comma,my goal is to append href link for the first value in the list ,col[0] namely,am running into following compilation error

```
INPUT:-
cols=['409452,  12345', '', '', 'This a test python script']

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-
 <tr>
<td><a href=http://data/409452>409452,<a href=http://data/12345>12345</a></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>This a test python script</td>
```

Python code:-

```
  cols=cols=['409452,  12345', '', '', 'This a test python script']

TEMPLATE = ['  <tr>']
for col in cols:
    value = col.split(",")  
    TEMPLATE.append(
        '    <td><a href=http://data/{}> {}</a></td>'.format(value)
TEMPLATE.append('  </tr>')
TEMPLATE = '\n'.join(TEMPLATE)
print TEMPLATE


Output I am getting:-


TEMPLATE.append('  </tr>')
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You are missing a ')' at the end of the first TEMPLATE.append.

Comment: if i try the below code ,am getting the erro     TEMPLATE.append('    <td><a href=http://data/{}> {}</a></td>'.format(*value))
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Could you paste your whole traceback, share a link from pastie.org or whatever suits you best.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza - here is the link http://pastie.org/5380643

Comment: I think your problem is with format method, check it here [string formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format) You could try that script without the .format() and see if that runs, then you could prove that your problem is there.

Comment: I took the liberty to try something myself, give it a look [my solution](http://pastie.org/5380745)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the missing `)` mentioned by others, your use of format is incorrect ([need to use `*value` to have it look for items in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3161594/462117)). (Your definition of cols also has the wrong indentation and has an extra `cols=`.)

This code works:

```
cols=['409452,  12345', '', '', 'This a test python script']

TEMPLATE = ['  <tr>']
for col in cols:
    if "," in col:
        value = col.split(",")
        value[:] = ['<a href=http://data/{0}>{0}</a>'.format(id.strip()) for id in value]
        col = ','.join(value)
    TEMPLATE.append('    <td>{}</td>'.format(col))
TEMPLATE.append('  </tr>')
TEMPLATE = '\n'.join(TEMPLATE)
print TEMPLATE
```

Output:

```
  <tr>
    <td><a href=http://data/409452>409452</a>,<a href=http://data/12345>12345</a></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>This a test python script</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: if i try the above code,am getting the following error    TEMPLATE.append('    <td><a href=http://data/{}> {}</a></td>'.format(*value))
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: It sounds like `value` contains fewer than two elements. Are you using the value of `cols` from my code? Try putting a `print value` before that line to see what's wrong.

Comment: ya..it doesn contain fewer than two elements sometimes,input should be cols=cols=['409452,  12345', '', '', 'This a test python script'],as you can see only the first value has two elements,sometimes there is no value and

Comment: `value` needs to have two elements, since you have two occurrences of `{}` in the string. You'll need to do something after the split to make sure `value` has enough elements, or maybe you'll need to do something else if `value` has only one item, or maybe you want to use `{0}` instead of `{}` (so that you get the first item of `value` in both places). You need to figure out what you want the code to do in that case.

Comment: you missed the whole point in my question,anyways thanks for trying

Comment: Sorry, I missed your "expected output" the first time around. I've updated my answer and I believe I have come closer to answering your question now, unless you also have different behavior in mind for the line with the comma. Is that supposed to be a separate link for each item separated by commas?

Comment: no probs..but it's still not my expected output..I will see what I can do unless you have any better idea

Comment: I've edited it again, and I think this is now what you're looking for. It doesn't match your output exactly -- your example output seems to be missing a `</a>` for the first item, which my version does output -- but that's easy for you to change if you need to be exactly the same (Get rid of `</a>` from where it is and put `+'</a>'` at end of next line). Sorry for not *reading* your question carefully enough before trying to answer it.

Comment: @user1795998: FWIW, I think this answer is on the right track.

Comment: You don't need to write `value[:] = ['<a href...strip()]` when a slightly simpler `value = ['<a href...strip()]` will do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown us your actual code (because there are not 13 lines in that sample, but your error message shows the error on line 13).  However, in this case I think the answer is reasonably simple...take a close look at this line:

```
TEMPLATE.append(
    '    <td><a href=http://data/{}> {}</a></td>'.format(value)
```

Remove the string to make it more obvious:

```
TEMPLATE.append(''.format(value)
```

As you can see, you're missing a closing `)`.